# Magento catalogCategoryAttributeList SOAP API call doesn't return all attributes

Tags: java, php, soap, magento, apache-axis

My goal is to get all attributes listed in Catalog -> Attributes -> Manage Attributes Admin Panel section using SOAP API call.

When I am calling

```
stub.catalogCategoryAttributeList(sessionId)
```

Note: Java, Apache Axis used to make this call. In php it's related to this call - http://www.magentocommerce.com/wiki/doc/webservices-api/api/catalog_category_attribute#catalog_category_attribute.list

I am getting a limited set of attributes for some reason. here is it:

```
increment_id
parent_id
updated_at
created_at
name
description
image
meta_title
meta_keywords
meta_description
is_active
all_children
path_in_store
children
url_key
url_path
path
position
level
display_mode
landing_page
is_anchor
available_sort_by
default_sort_by
custom_design
custom_design_apply
custom_design_from
custom_design_to
page_layout
custom_layout_update
```

I am missing some major attributes here for example here is some related to t-shirt properties:

```
color
gender
size
```

Comment: Which version of api are you using v1 or v2?

Answer (score 2):

I know this question is very old, but still trying to post a known answer as much possible, to make SO more knowledgeable.

What you are getting is perfectly okay, since the SOAP API "`catalogCategoryAttributeList`" will output the Category Attributes only & not the Product Attributes.

To get all the Catalog Product Attributes, you need to make a call to "`catalogProductAttributeList`" SOAP API, mentioned [here](http://www.magentocommerce.com/wiki/doc/webservices-api/api/catalog_product_attribute#catalog_product_attribute.list).

Hope it helps.